# What's our elevator pitch?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Throughout SE history (e.g. [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/278659)), there's been a lot of talk about providing an "elevator pitch" for a site. What is the site about, what's its goal, how would you describe it to someone unfamiliar with it or SE.

> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is about.
>
> This helps in visualising what your community is about and what it is going to be. If you have trouble describing your community in one-line, then its a sign that the community needs to take a relook at its scope and purpose.

Literature SE is still fairly young, and still having scope discussions which haven't been fully resolved, so I'm sure this question will be revisited at some point in the future. But I'm interested to see what people think right now about what we are and where we're going.

### **Briefly, in your personal opinion, what is Literature SE?**

<sub>This is *not* an attempt to make an 'official' elevator pitch for the site. All I'm trying to do is find out how various community members would describe the site, in the hope of learning something interesting e.g. from how these descriptions differ from each other. If this question doesn't get more than one or two answers, it's failed.</sub>